# How to get x64 process's exact location from an x86 process?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I am running a .net 5 Windows service process, which cannot be complied to AnyCPU.
For the user compatible reason(some client still use 32 bit Windows), I need to build it to x86 App.
When I try to enum the details of a x64 process on x64 Windows, it said a x86 process cannot do so.

Is there a workaround to get the x64 process's exact running path on x64 Windows?
e.g. running another x64 bit process and communicate with the process to get process info, but it's not graceful way. I wanna know if any better way exists?

Comment: clients that use 32-bit Windows can't query 64-bit process infos because there are no 64-bit processes running on those systems. Why don't just compile 2 different 32 and 64-bit versions?

Comment: the only reason to build a 32-bit version nowadays is just because there are some 3rd party binary libraries that are 32-bit only

Comment: @phuclv compile two different exe will bring deployment trouble, and some of our clients are still using 32 bit Windows.

Comment: Just select the correct 32 or 64-bit version by the installer. Lost of programs nowadays do that, no trouble at all. Or install both and use a small script/program to choose the correct executable at execution. But as I said, 32-bit Windows isn't the reason to not compile as AnyCPU unless you have to use some 32-bit only DLL